# How this If statement compiles without any error?

Tags: c#, compilation

When I was resolving merge conflicts, It appeared, that one of the conflict was automatically resolved by git in one of my code piece.

The code that rendered after merge conflict was:

```
if(condition1)
{
   //Statement 1

}
{
  //Statement 2

}
```

The code compiled and ran without any error. Is the statement 2 code piece serving as `else` here? if yes, then what is the use of `else` keyword?

Comment: No, the second `{}` is just in it's own scope for no apparent reason. What happens if you remove the braces?

Comment: That's right. The second pair braces simply define a code block - nothing to do with the first. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136853/why-does-c-sharp-allow-code-blocks-without-a-preceding-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got is an `if` statement followed by a block statement. The block statement introduces a new scope. They're two separate constructs.

It's often useful to introduce a block statement if you want to limit the lifetime of an object within your code. For example, you might only want to acquire a lock for a part of a function:

```
void DoSomething()
{
  // Stuff
  // Stuff
  // Stuff

  {
    Lock lock(mutex);    
  }

  // Stuff
  // Stuff
  // Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No the second {} is not a else statement but it just defines a scope ,did you try removing the braces and checking the output again?